# What happens when I remove an In-App Billing product from Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

It is possible to Deactivate or Delete an in-app billing product created in the Google Play Developer Console.

[image: Deactivating Managed Product in Google Play]

But it's not clear what the impact will be on current & future customers.

(1) If someone has already bought the item, and I later deactivate it, can they continue to have access to whatever app feature they purchased? Or will the in-app billing API reply that the product is invalid?

(2) What’s the difference between deactivating and deleting the product? If I had to guess, I'd say one lets users continue to use the feature, while deleting would deny those features and show up as if the product never existed.

Comment: Hey Manas !!! Did you found any answer for your question ? I have the similar situation like you. If you can help me out It would be gr8 for me...Thanks